# class getting kwargs from enclosing scope

Tags: python, dictionary, trie

Python seems to be inferring some kwargs from the enclosing scope of a class method, and I'm not sure why.  I'm implementing a Trie:

```
class TrieNode(object):
  def __init__(self, value = None, children = {}):
    self.children = children
    self.value = value

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key == "":
        return self.value
    return self.children[key[0]].__getitem__(key[1:])

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key == "":
        self.value = value
        return
    if key[0] not in self.children:
        self.children[key[0]] = TrieNode()
    self.children[key[0]].__setitem__(key[1:], value)
```

On the second to last line, I create a new TrieNode with, presumably, an empty dictionary of children.  However, when I inspect the resulting data structure, all of the TrieNodes in the tree are, using the same children dictionary.  Viz, if we do:

```
>>>test = TrieNode()
>>>test["pickle"] = 5
>>>test.children.keys()
['c', 'e', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'p']
```

Whereas the children of test should only consist of "p" pointing to a new TrieNode.  On the other hand, if we go into the second to last line of that code and replace it with:

```
        self.children[key[0]] = TrieNode(children = {})
```

Then it works as expected.  Somehow, then, the self.children dictionary is getting passed implicitly as a kwarg to TrieNode(), but why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're having a [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) issue.   Change your `__init__` function to be like this

```
def __init__(self, value=None, children=None):
    if not children:
        children = {}
```

The default value for children will only be evaluated once at the point of function creation, whereas you want it to be a new dict at within each call.

Here's a simple example of the problem using a list

```
>>> def f(seq=[]):
...     seq.append('x') #append one 'x' to the argument
...     print(seq) # print it
>>> f() # as expected
['x']
>>> f() # but this appends 'x' to the same list
['x', 'x']
>>> f() # again it grows
['x', 'x', 'x']
>>> f()
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
>>> f()
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

As the the answer I linked to describes, this bites every python programmer eventually.

Comment: To be clear, Python evaluates and assigns memory locations for default values once, at interpretation time; all further access (runtime) is just looking at that memory location. If you use a mutable object (list, dict), this is where problems arise.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are experiencing comes from the following line:

```
def __init__(self, value = None, children = {}):
```

The `children = {}` is called a [*mutable default argument*](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments). In this case the default arguments is constructed *one time* on function definition and every modification will affect every future function call (with the default value in use).
To fix this problem you should pass `None` as default value (since `None` is not mutable, the behavior is described above does not apply):

```
def __init__(self, value = None, children = None):
    self.children = children if children else {}
    self.value = value
```

Comment: I like to `self.children = children or {}`